# how to use flutter plugins and dart only instead of native android and ios without using method channels

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I am working on some how huge project related to mobile networks plugins, so I found that the only way is to do this by trying native plugins as after I fail in trying to read the data I need with flutter dart only.

So to imagine that let have a check the below Image..

[image: Data I need to read]

After seeing this I hope there's better way instead of completing the project writing native and read them with method channel, I'll thankful if there's any recommendation about docs or suggestions to do this project in fast and good way, as I am using multiple design patterns in multiple language like Java/Kotlin, swift(didn't start yet) and using the firebase as a back end and there's a lot of features like maps and measure download speed ...etc.

As I think this project could take a long time to finish :).

I hope this could be clear enough, note that I am using permissions as the below code for Android:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and This is the plugin I use..

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getDataNetworkType()

for more infos please check the below link:

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1945/files/f03a29122d3949ccde3453a635030eced2038cf4